# asp.net button.click() not triggering

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
function getInfo()
        {
            var UsrNameId = '<%=Txb_UserName.ClientID%>';
            var PswordId = '<%=Txb_Psswd.ClientID%>';

            if (FieldCheck(UsrNameId, PswordId))
            {
                document.getElementById('<%= Btn_Hidden.ClientID %>').click();
                alert("test");
            }
        }
```

i am using this JavaScript in the ASPx file 
i have a separate javascript file containing the following code

```
function FieldCheck(UserNameId,PasswordId)
{

    var Usr_Name = document.getElementById(UserNameId).value;
    if (Usr_Name == null || Usr_Name == "") {
        alert("Name Field Required");
        return false;
    }
    var Usr_Psswd = document.getElementById(PasswordId).value;
    if (Usr_Psswd == null || Usr_Psswd == "") {
        alert("Password Field Required");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

when i run the code and insert values into the required field i get an alert box containing the text "test" but the

```
document.getElementById('<%= Btn_Hidden.ClientID %>').click();
```

is not triggering 
the code on Btn_Hidden is :

```
protected void Btn_Hidden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lbl_Warning.Visible = true;
            if(Txb_UserName.Text!="Maurice")
            {
                Lbl_Warning.Text = "Wrong Username";
            }
            else if(Txb_Psswd.Text!="admin")
            {
                Lbl_Warning.Text = "Wrong Password";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Welcome.html?");
            }

        }
```

the code writen on the 2 asp buttons is :

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_Submit" runat="server"  OnClientClick="getInfo()" Text="Login" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn_Hidden" OnClick="Btn_Hidden_Click"/>
```

Comment: this `getInfo` must return true or false, depend from what you like to do.

Comment: @Aristos doesn't mattre tried both true and false the click event is not triggering

Comment: I tried it and `Btn_Hidden_Click` is hit in code-behind when I click on `Btn_Submit`. Since you said that the `alert` was displayed, I tested with only the `click` and the `alert` statements in the client function. Is any other property of `Btn_Hidden` set in code-behind?

Comment: @connorsFan nope this is all the code

Comment: That code is correct. There's something else a-foot here. Maybe a JavaScript scoping issue. Can you run it in chrome and press F12, look at the console tab and see if you get any errors? Not interested in messages or warnings... just errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked "Btn_Submit" button whole page is PostBack.
to solve problems you must add ScriptManager like below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Txb_UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Txb_Psswd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button ID="Btn_Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="getInfo()" Text="Login" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn_Hidden" OnClick="Btn_Hidden_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```